# What's the meaning of "degrees" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english

I found this use of the word «degree» in a sentence of a contemporary American novel. A woman looks discouraged at her old and shabby kitchen. I understand everything except how to interpret the word «degrees». It cannot refer to temperature, because 40° F is too low for the oven to overheat, and the woman lives in Texas where the weather is definitely not cold! What does it mean?

> She looked at the cracks in the old subway tile on the counter **and the oven that was off by forty degrees**. The leaky faucet and sticky drawers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it *does* refer to temperature. The thermostat on the oven was inaccurate by a margin of 40 degrees - that is, the actual temperature was either that much lower or that much higher than the one selected.

Comment: It might also mean that the oven's position was off by 40 degrees (unit of angle measure). But I think that your interpretation is more likely.

Comment: Yes, I think it makes sense

Comment: I would wonder how she knew that the oven was 'off' by that amount.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well, I know that my oven is off by about 15 degrees, because I have an oven thermometer in there (and I also knew before I bought the thermometer, because everything I baked took longer than instructed, until I started raising the temperature by 15 degrees over what was recommended each time)